# Trying to make a program with dialogues, crashes on start

Tags: java, android, dialog, crash

**So it seems the error is in the button inside the dialogue, don't know how to fix it**

I have an assignment to make a program that captures values from EditText in dialogues and then uses them for a simple equation... I must say I am very new at programming for android and therefore don't know much but the program keeps crashing when i run it, I have no idea why and can't detect any problems on my own, I'll add the code, If anyone can detect any (or many) problems please point them out, thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Dialog d1;
Integer r1, r2, vol, vot;
EditText ed1;
TextView txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button btn3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button btn4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button btn5= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    final TextView txt1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final TextView txt2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final TextView txt3= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    final TextView txt4=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    final int r1= Integer.valueOf(1000);
    final int r2=Integer.valueOf(1000);
    final int vol=Integer.valueOf(10);




btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        final Dialog d1 = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        d1.setContentView(R.layout.valor);
        d1.setTitle("Valor de R1");
        final EditText ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        d1.show();
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int r1=Integer.parseInt(ed1.getText().toString());
                txt1.setText(String.valueOf(r1));}
                catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
                {
                    nfe.printStackTrace();
                }
                txt1.setText(String.valueOf(r1));
                d1.dismiss();
            };
        });
    }
});
**NOTE: THIS SAME SEQUENCE IS REPEATED TWICE MORE FOR THE 2 OTHER VARIABLES **

btn5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        vot=(r2/(r1+r2))*vol;
        txt4.setText("Resultado: " +String.valueOf(vot));
    };
});}
```

Logcat:

```
03-12 21:06:12.781: E/ViewRootImpl(29660): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
03-12 21:06:17.966: D/AndroidRuntime(29660): Shutting down VM
03-12 21:06:17.966: W/dalvikvm(29660): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d11700)
03-12 21:06:17.971: E/AndroidRuntime(29660): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 21:06:17.971: E/AndroidRuntime(29660): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 21:06:17.971: E/AndroidRuntime(29660):    at com.uia.examenno1.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:49)
03-12 21:06:17.971: E/AndroidRuntime(29660):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4489)
03-12 21:06:17.971: E/AndroidRuntime(29660):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18803)
03-12 21:06:17.971: E/AndroidRuntime(29660):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-12 21:06:17.971: E/AndroidRuntime(29660):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-12 21:06:17.971: E/AndroidRuntime(29660):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 21:06:17.971: E/AndroidRuntime(29660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
03-12 21:06:17.971: E/AndroidRuntime(29660):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 21:06:17.971: E/AndroidRuntime(29660):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-12 21:06:17.971: E/AndroidRuntime(29660):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
03-12 21:06:17.971: E/AndroidRuntime(29660):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
03-12 21:06:17.971: E/AndroidRuntime(29660):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: none, it just stops, or not one that I see atleast

Comment: if you are using Eclpise or another IDE enable logcat and there should be some output to why it crashed.

Comment: So now I tested this and what comes out is a mess... I can't understand it

Comment: i posted the logs if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you aren't handling any exception it will crash anyways because txt1.toString() might not be parsed to an Integer. You should instead do txt1.getText().toString(). Also please attach your log if this is not causing issue and you might consider reading refactoring books :

```
try {
    Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    nfe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: ok I believe this was the problem since i changed the first parses and it runs but then stops when i open a dialog, so uhm now i guess i need to properly parse the ones in the dialog, will this method you put here work?

Comment: if your EditText is part of your dialog why are you using findViewById  which is attached to the activity.And you still have same issue as i mentioned above in int r1=Integer.parseInt(ed1.toString()); Also you seem to be parsing text in ed1 to Integer and changing it back to String when setting it to txt1. While you could have just done txt1.setText(ed1.getText());

Comment: with the edit text... then what? do i declare it outside of the Dialog? also the others i already corrected in the actual project, let me also reflect that on the code of this post

Answer (score 0):

your `d1.setContentView` Method is not trust.
try to use from default android layout by use `android.r.layout.simple_list_item_1`

Comment: it works actually... i've narrowed down the fault to the button setup inside the dialogue... just don't know how to fix it

Comment: your `ContetntView` should have a place to `Title` and `Edittext`

Comment: the dialog used is an outside activity